# parentNode not deleting properly

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, parent-node

my javascript knowledge is pretty poor. I'm trying to run a script with greasemonkey on http://www.twitch.tv/directory/all to remove certain kinds of streams from the list based on an image provided next to a shot of the stream(like picture of hearthstone, minecraft etc.). Here's the code:

```
//what you want to remove    
var killIt=["http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Hearthstone%3A%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft-138x190.jpg", "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-138x190.jpg", "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Minecraft-138x190.jpg"];
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("boxart");
//runthrough elements killing certain ones
for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < killIt.length; i++) {
        if (el[i].src == killIt[j]) {
            var ely = el[i].parentNode;
            ely.parentNode.removeChild(ely);
        }
    }
}
```

So i tried it on w3schools site and the code works fine, but when i try to actually run it in twitch.tv it does nothing(seemingly).
Am i missing something about parent nodes? Or greasemonkey?

Comment: Second for should be `j++`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 dude, make it an answer :)

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 2):

The second `for` should be `j++`. Also you can use `.indexOf` to test if the URL is listed in the array to avoid a other for loop.